# Problem: jQuery change css when input[type="radio"] is checked (value)

Tags: jquery, css, forms, radio-button

I want to change the css (display:block;) of a div with the data-id="group-vraag" when the a radiobutton is checked with the value="Vraag" and when the radiobutton is unchecked change the css to (display: none;)

I can't get it to work.

**Edit: As u can see in the screenshot; both radio use `[name="radio-keuze"]`. I specifically want to target the one with 'Vraag'. Could I use `.wpcf7-list-item .first` for this?**

```
$('input[type=radio][name="radio-keuze"]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Vraag') {
        $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"block"});
    }
  else if($(this).val() == '') {
        $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"none"});
    }
});
```

Here is the html
[image]

Comment: The Value of the Radio never changes. One of the properties, `checked` will change from `true` to `false`. So you will not want to review the Value but instead review the `checked` property of the input.

Comment: So could I use `.wpcf7-list-item .first` and then when the `input[type="radio"]:checked` then `$('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"block"});`. What will the jQuery code be? (Im new to this)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="radio-keuze"]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Vraag') {
        $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"block"});
    }
  else if($(this).val() == '') {
        $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"none"});
    }
});
```

I added "" around type=radio.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, I've updated the screenshot with some extra html code. Maybe u see something I don't (I'm pretty new to jQuery btw)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check if the radio is `checked`. jQuery has a quick way to check for this as a selector, `:checked`. You can do this like so:

```
$('input[value="Vraag"]').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"block"});
  } else {
    $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"none"});
  }
});
```

You can also do this:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="radio-keuze"]').change(function() {
  if($(this).prop("checked") && $(this).val() == "Vraag") {
    $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"block"});
  } else {
    $('div[data-id="group-vraag"]').css({"display":"none"});
  }
});
```

There are lots of ways to confirm one specific element has been changed.

Comment: As u can see in the screenshot; both radio use `[name="radio-keuze"]`. I specifically want to target the one with 'Vraag'. Could I use `.wpcf7-list-item .first` for this?

Comment: @Max that was not clear from your post. I have updated my answer.